# definitive location for wso2 5.x sources

Tags: git, svn, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a definitive location for the full WSO2 5.x Platform source code?  I'm specifically looking for what Identity Server is built on.  I was able to get the Identity Server project for 5.0.0 at https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity, but I need more projects than that, namely everything it's build upon that is WSO2 code.  From what I've gathered between the WSO2 documentations, their SVN repo, and github, it doesn't appear to be all out there, or even in the same place.  I seem to only be able to get 4.x sources for the carbon kernel with other core things, which seem complete... and at least with the svn, there are duplicates in places.  ...confused!

I'd love to be able to look through the 5.0.0+ sources of things such as org.wso2.carbon.user.core (AbstractUserStoreManager, etc...) to learn how the defaults are working, etc... 
For that I had found older sources at: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/trunk/core/
But the most similar thing I could find at github was the carbon-kernel project, doesn't have this or a similar sub-projects I can discern.

(i wanted to post my links for places I tried, but my reputation is too new to share them... believe me

Comment: in the the wso2 svn, the closest i could find was in /repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/trunk/core/, but wasn't stuff moving to git?

Comment: Do you want the source of WSO2 IS?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is nothing call WSO2 5.x Platform. At the moment latest released WSO2 products are based on Carbon kernel version 4.2.0 (e.g. ESB 4.8.1, AS 5.2.1, etc..) WSO2 has release carbon kernel 4.4.0 few months ago and products that are based on kernel version 4.4.0 will be release pretty soon.
You can get all the WSO2 product source from the [github](https://github.com/wso2) 
If you want the source of WSO2-IS you can refer [WSO2-IS](https://github.com/wso2/product-is)

Comment: Hi @thusitha thanks for the clarification on the versions.  I was assuming that IS 5.0.0 was built on Carbon 5.0.0.  Is there a chart that lines up versions concurrent with each other, or do we just need to wander through the POM files, which I guess is no biggie, but didn't think of it? :)

Comment: I did pull the IS sources from github and got confused seeing 4.x versions of Carbon.  FYI some WSO2 building from source still refer to using SVN, such as here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Building+from+Source ...but everything's in github now right?

Comment: you can refer to carbon release matrix http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

Comment: yes. Now everything is in the github :) you don't have to use svn source any more